# iOS what is difference between Different type of app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am beginner in iOS and I know this is basic question but it creates confusin many times for me and faced several issue due to app delegate declaration. 
What is the difference between this all type of appdelegate declaration and when we are declared it?

**1) when we declared appdelegate as object like this .**

```
//in viewcontroller.h file

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FriendsViewController.h"
#import "XMPPStream.h"
@class AppDelegate;
@interface ViewController :UIViewController<XMPPStreamDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
    UIView *padding;
    AppDelegate *appdelegate;
}
```

**2) when we declared appdelegate in Properties.**

```
//in viewcontroller.h file
@property (weak, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appdelegate;
```

**3) when we declare appdelegate in viewcontroller.m file to make object.**

```
//in viewcontroller.m file
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

**4) when we declare appdelegate like this**

```
// in Viewcontroller.m file
+(AppDelegate *) sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

**Difference**

```
- (AppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

I know this is basic question but many people like me face difficulty to declare.

Comment: can i delete this ? why i am getting - marking ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**First** one is used to create private object of class.

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate;
```

**Second** one is used to create public and global object of class, used ***property attributes***.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appdelegate;
```

but first two are just object declaration
**Third, fourth and fifth are same**, differance is dot(.) is used for getter and setter method, square brackets shows that it is not a property, instead it is a class method of that class.

In declared object you are passing instance of your appDelegate

4th case is `class methods` and 5th case is `instance method`

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//or
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Comment: Instead of giving negative mark, if you have better answer then it will be great if you share your answer or at least correct my answer.

Comment: sorry sujay . you are true sujay. can i delete this ?

Comment: @BadalShah, that comment was not for you, anyway you are free to ask questions, so no need to delete it.

Comment: hmmmm. i understand. but i feel sorry because of me you got negative marketing so. they can't understand.